# How to run multiple excel sheets with same R code

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have a excel worksheet which consists of 28 sheets each having 5 common column and different number of rows. first column is "date", 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th column are statistical data based on which further time series analysis to be carried out for all 28 countries (sheets). How to proceed?

Comment: please provide your code if you have tried anything

Answer (score 1):

You can load all of the sheets in from a spreadsheet with `readxl`.

```
library(readxl)
filename <- "myfile.xlsx"
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
data <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X, skip = 0))
names(data) <- sheets
```

You can easily apply functions on the data with `lapply` from base R. Just replace the `...` with your code. You can access the dataframe with the `x` variable.

```
lapply(data, function(x){...})
```

Comment: thank you arun kumar mahesh ji. your codes are working.

Comment: sir now at the next level how to proceed the "some set of codes" for each and every sheets

Comment: I edited my answer with a general way to apply functions to the data.